# Select only distinct values for a particular column mysql

Tags: mysql

We have two tables in mysql database.Screenshots are attached below.

[Given table ads_testTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf3F1.png)

[image: Given table ads_testTable]

[here is the screenshot of my dimesnionvalue_flattable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlDr9.png)

[image: here is the screenshot of my dimesnionvalue_flattable]

We have to run a query like the one below.

```
SELECT Quiz_Attempt.L1_Key dimID, 
       Quiz_Attempt.L1_Label CatVars,
       COALESCE(**xyz**,0) AS series0 
FROM DSQ_ADSSCHEMA.ADS_TestTable dataTable   
RIGHT OUTER JOIN LS_CONFIG.DSQ_DIMENSIONVALUES_FLAT Quiz_Attempt on dataTable.Quiz_Attempt = Quiz_Attempt.L1_Key  
WHERE Quiz_Attempt.L0_Key = 'All Levels' AND
      Quiz_Attempt.DimensionID = 'Packet'  
GROUP BY Quiz_Attempt.L1_Key, Quiz_Attempt.L1_Label;
```

My motive is to write a query in place of **xyz** so that I can get avg of obtainedMarks column in testtable according to the value of **dimID** I get.Each distinct Quiz_Attempt is a different test so If a Packet is repeating for a particular Quiz_Attempt in testTable, it should take only one value for that AttemptID.

Comment: Can you be more precise on how you determine if two quiz attempts are the same? 

Which one should be used when two quiz attempts are determined to be the same?

Comment: Quiz_attempts are same on their id. and all quiz attempt will have same marks obtained. This ads_testtable is actually result of exploding quiz_attempts which are part of multiple programs and packets.

Comment: So, in your screenshot, the first 4 rows are the same?

Comment: Yes, they are for same quiz only. So only one of them will be applicable for marks obtained.

Answer (score 0):

I think you query could take the form of:

```
SELECT 
  L1_Key dimID, 
  L1_Label CatVars,
  COALESCE('**xyz**',0) AS series0 
FROM (
  SELECT *  
  FROM (SELECT * FROM ADS_TestTable GROUP BY ADS_TestTable.Quiz_Attempt) dataTable
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN DSQ_DIMENSIONVALUES_FLAT Quiz_Attempt on dataTable.Quiz_Attempt = Quiz_Attempt.L1_Key  
  WHERE Quiz_Attempt.L0_Key = 'All Levels' AND
        Quiz_Attempt.DimensionID = 'Packet' 
  GROUP BY dataTable.Quiz_Attempt
) A GROUP BY dimID, CatVars;
```

The JOIN is done in an inner query, and grouped by Quiz_Attempt, so that you get a single row per attempt. This result is then used to compute what you need.